# Gaussian_KDE contour density/km^2

Tags: python, kernel-density, scipy

I am currently using gaussian_kde to do KDE on a set of coordinate points (each point represents a case). I am able to get out contours which is great; however, when I look at the actual contour level values, they seem to be extremely high (e.g. 1284 when it should be closer to 20 cases/km^2 at the highest). I was hoping to define levels as cases/km^2; however, I can't seem to get that output from scipy. Does anyone know how I'd get that data?

Code for reference:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde


# plot out map itself
census_tracts = gpd.read_file('../app/static/census.geojson')
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
census_tracts.plot(ax=ax,facecolor="none", edgecolor='black', zorder=1)

x, y = # geographic coordinates of the cases.
xi, yi = np.mgrid[x.min():x.max():100j,y.min():y.max():100j]

positions = np.vstack([xi.ravel(), yi.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([x,y])

k = gaussian_kde(values, bw_method=0.1)

f = np.reshape(k(positions).T, xi.shape)


linsep = np.linspace(min(k(positions).T), max(k(positions).T), 7)
print(linsep)
ax.contourf(xi, yi, f, np.linspace(linsep[1], max(k(positions).T), 6), 
            alpha=0.5)
```